# Why can't I install Timeshift?

Tags: software-center, timeshift

Why can't I install Timeshift via the command line?

```
sudo apt install timeshift
[sudo] password for linuxkidinside: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package timeshift
```

Can't find it on Ubuntu Software either.

[image: Ubuntu Software]

after sudo apt update Ign:7

```
Ign:7 ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:8 ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release
404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
```

after sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/timeshift

```
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/timeshift/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
Latest release of Timeshift
More info: https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/timeshift
Adding repository.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-timeshift-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-timeshift-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-timeshift.gpg with fingerprint 1B32B87ABAEE357218F6B48CB5B116B72D0F61F0
Hit:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:4 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:5 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/timeshift/ubuntu jammy InRelease [17.5 kB]
Err:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Get:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/timeshift/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [584 B]
Get:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/timeshift/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [308 B]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You've not provided your OS/release details; are we to guess?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=timeshift&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all   If you're using a release that has it, have you enabled `universe` ?

Comment: Assuming this app is the backup app referenced here this is a step by step installing and using it. https://www.makeuseof.com/use-timeshift-backup-and-restore-linux-snapshots/

Comment: That info should be in the question. That is extremely old software circa 2002 and most likely can not run on a modern version of Ubuntu. The error simply tells you there is no version for Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Please stop using comments to add info to the question. Use edit to add the info to the question so everyone can find it without have having to read through comments.

Comment: Question is edited.

Comment: but on youtube same Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, they can find the Timeshift on Ubuntu Software and install using sudo apt install timeshift. Mine, I can't do either.

Comment: I added universe and sudo apt update but, I can't still install the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: I appreciate your help guys! Especially for bringing Grub Customizer up.

I did a fresh install to remove the Grub Customer and I was able to install Timeshift.

Cheers everyone!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)